# Cannot uninstall wine

Tags: wine, software-uninstall

Just as the title says I've been trying for about an hour now to uninstall wine, and no matter what I try I can't seem to make any headway. I keep getting this error::

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge wine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 wine-unstable:i386 : Depends: wine32-unstable:i386 (>= 1.7.15-0.1) but it is not installable or
                               wine64-unstable:i386 (>= 1.7.15-0.1) but it is not installable

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

any help at all is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Did you use a Thir Party Repository to install that version of Wine? Latest on 15.04 is Wine 1.6.2. And if you did, did you disable the repository before trying to remove it?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get autoremove wine `

Comment: "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:" it says... and when you did that ...?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Source:

http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-wine-1-9-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
sudo apt purge wine*
sudo apt autoremove
rm -r .wine
```